# When I move to another user's profile page, the {{ user }} tag on base.html for the project (not app) changes. how do I stop it from doing this?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a sort of facebook replica, but whenever I go to someone else's profile page, It automatically logs in to their account. I looked at the code, and it seems like the 'user' object  in base.hmtl keeps changing. here's what I have:

accounts.views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth
from groups.models import Group
from posts.models import Post
from friends.models import Friend

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/home.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
                return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error': "An account with this username already exists"})
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect('groups:index')



        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error':'The passwords do not match'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

            user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])

            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect('groups:index')
            else:
                return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'error':"An account with this information does not exist"})

    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

def logout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auth.logout(request)
        return redirect('accounts:login')


def profile(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    groups = user.group_set.all()
    posts = Post.objects.filter(author=user)
    # get grabs one instance, so you grab an instance of friend.
    # you locate the friends list by its owner, which is 'current_user' in this case
    friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
    friends = friend.users.all()
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {'user':user, 'groups':groups, 'posts':posts, 'friends':friends})
```

when you click on a link another user's profile page from your own profile page, it takes you to that user, but also logs into their profile.

accounts.profile.html:

```
<h2>My Friends</h2>
          <div class="my_friends">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              {% for friend in friends %}
                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{% url 'accounts:profile' friend.id %}">{{friend.username}}</a></li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </div>
```

the url file for accounts is here:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path


app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('profile/<int:user_id>', views.profile, name='profile'),

]
```

the {{ user }} object keeps changing, I need to stop it from doing this. 
base.hmtl:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<p>Signed in as: {{user}}</p>

<a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('logout').submit()}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off login_out"></span></a>

<form id='logout' action="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" >
</form>

<div class="sessions_info">
<a href="{% url 'accounts:profile'  %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user profile-icon"></span></a>
</div>


{% else %}
<a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in login_out"></span></a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: How can you tell that you’re logged in as that user? Maybe the place with that information also uses `{{ user }}`?

Comment: ok, so I am actually staying logged in. the problem is that the {{ .user }} object in base.html keeps changing! hoe do I stop it from doing this?

Comment: isn't the {{ user }} object in base.html always the currently logged in user?

Comment: Not if you override it. Pick a different name, like `{'profile': user, …}`.

Comment: I dont have a view file for my project. this is the base.html from the project, not the app

Comment: @Ry︁ can I create a view file for base.html?

Comment: You can use another context in your template. Using `context-processer` or just passing other context exactly you want.

Answer (score 0):

The place where you are setting the variable `user` to display the logged-in user name is not shown in your code.

Anyway, since you are getting the profile details of the user into the variable `user`, it's getting displayed across `Signed in as:` label.

The logged-in user details could be easily obtained from `request.user`, without interfering with any context data. Check the output of the following...

```
<p>Signed in as: {{request.user}}</p>
```

Comment: @Robert Columbia: Done!